# How to fix the error java.net.UnknownHostException while using Spring Boot and Eureka Server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, resttemplate, netflix-eureka

I have a Spring Boot microservice called "documents-microservice", which is registered in Eureka Server. I am trying to access this microservice using its name in the URL and with `RestTemplate`, as the following:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response =    restTemplate.exchange("http://documents-microservice/document-name", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

Although I am sure that the service name is available on Eureka Server which is running on port 8761 (See picture below), I still get the following errors:

[image: Eureka Server Running]

Errors:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://documents-microservice/document-name": documents-microservice; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: documents-microservice
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:539)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.controller.util.CircularsControllerUtil.circularListView(CircularsControllerUtil.java:196)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.controller.CircularsController.viewCircularList(CircularsController.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:335)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:610)
    at ae.gov.adm.common.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: documents-microservice
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:660)
    ... 52 more
I/O error on POST request for "http://documents-microservice/document-name": documents-microservice; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: documents-microservice
```

**Update:** Please note that I have the following method in the client for setting RestTemplate:

```
    @Bean //this methods will be executed only once to avoid getting multiple instances.
    @LoadBalanced //I will not give you service URL, but rather a hint for what you need to discover.
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate()
    {
         final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

         System.out.println("rest template defined");

         return  restTemplate;
    }
```

**Update:** Please note that currently, my client code is not a Spring Boot Application.

Answer (score 5):

There are several things that you need to do:

- first: you need the RestTemplate configuration not in the client, but in the **service(1)** that calls that client

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {

    @Bean @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

- second: you need the corresponding dependencies in the pom.xml of the same **service(1)**
- third: add `@EnableDiscoveryClient` in your main application

And **other configurations**, but you must provide a full example to help you more.
This [example](https://github.com/didorg/ms_technology_1) can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by name "documents-microservice"  via a @Feign client, otherwise you should try the gateway EG, hqtpm001....:8081

Furthermore, Eureka server is not the host of the application, it is more or less the traffic cop and lets you as the client know where to go to get the application.  aka the Service Registry

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know all about Eureka Server and I created a Service Registry using Eureka Server Jar files, and it is running as I showed. But based on my knowledge, you only need to include the tag LoadBalanced annotation in the client so that it works, but it is not working in my code. Perhaps because my client is not Spring Boot App? By the way if you are sure of @Feign client idea, I would appreciate it if you can show how it is done by code. Thanks.

Comment: Ribbon is the client side load balancer. 
`
@FeignClient("stores")
public interface StoreClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/stores")
    List<Store> getStores();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/stores/{storeId}", consumes = "application/json")
    Store update(@PathVariable("storeId") Long storeId, Store store);
}
`
some good articles for ya. 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html

Comment: I don't think I need Ribbon to fix my problem, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

**Incase if you want to use OpenFeign instead RestTemplate**

- name refers to name of service registered with eureka
- doctors registration service is registered with eureka server with this name doctors-registration-application.

> @FeignClient(name = "doctors-registration-application")  public
> interface DoctorDetailsClient {
>
> @GetMapping("/doctor/get-by-Id/{doctorId}")     public Doctor
> getDoctorDetails(@PathVariable int doctorId);
> @GetMapping("/doctor/get-by-name/{name}")   public Doctor
> getDoctorDetailsByName(@PathVariable String name);     }